# Get a wrong answer when init a UInt64 type in Swift

Tags: swift

[image]

Why get a wrong answer when I put `+ 100` into `UInt64()` ?

Comment: It's overflowing the integer in the 2nd case (because it's not being converted into a UInt64 until after the addition).

Comment: @Buddy I find that `let testLength: UInt64 = UInt64(Double(powf(2, 35)) + Double(100))` could get the correct answer. It seems about the way to store float number's value in memory. Thx.

Answer (score 3):

I fear you are hitting the `float` precision limit:

```
powf(2, 35) + 100 == powf(2, 35) // true
```

Try the double version:

```
let testLength: UInt64 = UInt64(pow(2, 35) + 100.0)
```

As a role of thumb it might help having a look at what the playground shows you for:

```
powf(2, 35)      // 3.435974e+10
pow(2.0, 35.0)   // 34359738368
```

In the float version your 100 is out

Comment: Thx. You are right. When I try `let testLength: UInt64 = UInt64(Double(powf(2, 35)) + Double(100)), I get the correct answer...